# Invitations sent to Gmail do not appear in Calendar while invitations sent to Office 365 do

Tags: macos, mail.app, calendar, gmail, office-365

When I receive meeting invitations to my Gmail account they appear as regular mails with an attachment. Opening the message in Gmail lets me add the event to my Google Calendar, making it appear in OS X Calendar after the next sync.

However, when I receive invitations to my Office 365 account they appear in OS X Calendar "incoming invitations" menu bar item. They also show up as grey tentative bookings in the calendar.

Why don't Gmail invitations work like Office 365 invitations? Can I make Gmail invitations appear in OS X Calendar?

N.B., I don't use the Gmail account in Mail.app, but I do use the Office 365 account there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get better native integration, but Outlook 2016 and O365 sure does a good job with gmail and other email being integrated. It's not the typical Apple experience, but it's dramatically better than 2011 and much older Office suite.